# Capture template output on the fly

Tags: ansible

I need to run a command on the target server that accepts data through stdin only. The data I'm feeding it comes from a template file and contains sensitive data, so I'd rather not have it sitting in the filesystem even for a second.

I'm trying to find a way to grab the output of a template task so I can pass it to the command. Something like:

```
- name: generate data
  template:
    src: data.j2
    dest: [I'd rather not have any files written]
  register: myvar

- name: run command
  shell: "command < {{ myvar }}"
```

Is a better way to go about this that doesn't involve writing a temporary file, feeding it to the command and then erasing it?

Comment: Did that once as you described, with temporary file. Created feature request for ansible guys: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22134

Answer (score 7):

Got answer from ansible guys:

```
some_var: "{{ lookup('template', 'tmpl.j2') }}"
```

Comment: Great! If you're using "with_items" with your task then you can use "item" variable in template.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way of handling commands which need input from `stdin` is the [expect](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html) module.

The proper way of dealing with sensitive data with Ansible is [ansible vault](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html). One way or the other the data will sit unencrypted on the file system as Ansible creates Python scripts to execute the commands defined under tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Combining a couple of earlier answers here, we get:

```
- name: run command
  command: "command"
  args:
    stdin: "{{ lookup('template', 'tmpl.j2') }}"
```